# Can the "glow" notification on Firefox 4's App Tabs be disabled?

Tags: firefox

Firefox 4's App Tabs have a feature where an App Tab with new content (e.g., a new mail arrives in Gmail) will cause the tab to "glow" until it is revisited, similar in spirit to badge notifications in Mac OS X and iOS.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: Glow on Firefox 4 App Tab]

Is there a way to disable this?  While it is a nice feature, I keep distractions and interruptions on my desktop to a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no option for this as far as I know, but you can disable or change the color in your `userChrome.css`.

If you've never done that, locate your Firefox profile, which will be placed dependent on you OS type (see [How do I find my profile?](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile)).

Change to the `chrome` directory in it, and edit or create the `userChrome.css` file to contain these lines:

```
.tabbrowser-tab[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]) {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

That should do it until Mozilla changes things.

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: FTR, doesn't work anymore in Firefox 29.